# Get Request Works in Postman but gives a 403 When Request is Called through HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, authentication

I'm trying to access an Amazon Prometheus Server but am getting an authentication error when the request is done through a Java API, although it works on Postman when the request is the same.

Note: The Authentication setup currently is done through AWS Signature Version 4 Signing (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)

Here are the logs from Prometheus, showing all Request Headers used (hiding some potentially sensitive info)

```
GET https://{resource}-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/api/v1/query

Host: {resource}-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Security-Token: FwoGZXIvYXdzEB4aDPxYxIKgd5JznR9gOyKkAkoDbjeTi79mRDgU6Hdd2AGlLwKnNGySAkNYwmKItTcSssS9zNZ+/s..........................................==
X-Amz-Date: 20221207T201649Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={AccessKey}/20221207/us-east-1/{Resource}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: `*`/`*`
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ea3f71dd-db52-4869-a48a-2cf5f72d15b3`
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

If I copy almost this same Request using a Java API, it gives a 403 error.
Note: I'm making sure to include the `X-Amz-Security-Token` since this request needs a session token.

```java
try { 

    final URL url = new URL("https://{resource}-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/api/v1/query");


    final HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "{resource}-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Amz-Security-Token", "FwoGZXIvYXdzEB4aDPxYxIKgd5JznR9gOyKkAkoDbjeTi79mRDgU6Hdd2AGlLwKnNGySAkNYwmKItTcSssS9zNZ+/s..........................................==");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Amz-Date", "20221207T201649Z");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={AccessKey}/20221207/us-east-1/{Resource}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "`*`/`*`");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Postman-Token", "ea3f71dd-db52-4869-a48a-2cf5f72d15b3");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");


    responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();  // 403 here
}
```

Things I've attempted:

- Creating my own Signature instead of reusing the same made from the Postman request
- Including/excluding some header properties set including: `User-Agent`, `Accept`, `Cache-Control`, `Postman-Token`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Connection`.

Any ideas on what could be leading to this 403 response?

Thanks

I tried to make a request to an AWS service using Signature Version 4 Signing - expecting a 200 response but getting a 403.

Comment: Why are you not using the [existing libraries](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/amp/package-summary.html) to access it?  This is far easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar , I'll look into switching over to that library!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer to this and wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this issue.

A couple of things.

First, if you copy the same request generated from Postman **it will not work.** This is because AWS Signature Version 4 generates a unique Signature after every request. So if you copy this "Authentication" header field, it's going to give you a 403. That leads me to...

Second, you need to generate your own signature through Amazon's [four-step process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). This can get very confusing if try to code it on your own. I would suggest trying two things. Either use [AWS4Signer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWS4Signer.html) and utilize the sign method or follow the [example AWS provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-java) (this is what I ultimately chose).

Download that Zip and check out the GET example. Make sure you put the "x-amz-security-token" on the header if your request requires a session. And lastly, **make sure your URL includes the encoded query parameter**. This is what I spent most of my time on. My URL/query parameters looked something like this -

```
String notEncodedQueryParameter = "avg(process_runtime_jvm_classes_current_loaded{stack_name=\"dev\"})";
String encodedQueryParameter = URLEncoder.encode(notEncodedQueryParameter, "UTF-8");
new URL("https://aps-workspace-amazonaws.com/api/v1/query?query="+ encodedQueryParameter);

final Map<String, String> queryParameters = new HashMap<>();
queryParameters.put("query", notEncodedQueryParameter);
```

Then later I passed my query parameters to get encoded as part of the authorization signature being generated.

```
   String authorization = signer.computeSignature(headers,
                                               queryParameters, 
                                               AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256,
                                               awsAccessKey,
                                               awsSecretKey);
```

I really recommend using that second link because if you don't get the correct response, it will give you a useful error message like

> the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
> provided canonical request has different parameter encoding

Instead of just leaving you with a 403 error.

Best of luck.